# Do I need a Visa to Croatia with a Lebanese passport if I have an EU member state visa?

Tags: eu, romania, croatia, bulgaria, lebanese-citizens

I've read on some websites that it is not required to have a visa to go into Croatia/Romania/Bulgaria/Bosnia for Lebanese citizens with an Eu member state visa. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

If you hold an EU member state visa, such as Cyprus, you can visit the aforementioned countries as well as Serbia. However, the criteria is different from country to another (required number of entries, duration of stay, etc.). You can fill and check your info here and get the detailed criteria for each country: https://www.emirates.com/ae/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx